# If data from a column matches data in another row csv php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to find out if you could use php code to look at part of a product sku from a column within a row of a csv and if the part of the data matches add the sku to another column.

I already have the code to read and create the new csv, but I can not get it to look at every roe and match data

Comment: Please start with [tour] and [mcve].

Comment: *"I already have the code to read and create the new csv"* - Right; "you" have it.